# Pandas not raising an exception when reading malformed data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

The following is malformed (5 columns but 6 values) But pandas does not throw an exception.

```
timestamp,col1,col2,col3,col4
1540998000,XY,40000764,G1-FDD:0,13.90,13.90
1540998000,XY,40000764,C1-FDD:0,-102.80,-102.80
1540998000,XY,40000764,C1-FDD:1,-102.80,-102.80
```

The following is how pandas reads it.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.read_csv("some_20181031-150205.csv")
           timestamp  col1     col2           col3       col4
1540998000     XY  40000764  G1-FDD:0         13.9       13.9
1540998000     XY  40000764  C1-FDD:0       -102.8     -102.8
1540998000     XY  40000764  C1-FDD:1       -102.8     -102.8
```

Why is it not raising an exception?

The first column values are actual values and have not been altered.

Thanks,
Anoop

Comment: It assumes that the first column is the index. This behavior is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pandas assumes an index

This is by design. The first "column" is treated as an **index** and therefore does not need to be named. To understand this, you must appreciate every dataframe *must* have an index, whether explicitly specified or not. For example, notice the values `0, 1, 2` along the left:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((3, 5)))

print(df)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.244763  0.994879  0.085906  0.330168  0.269433
1  0.849739  0.631897  0.372024  0.413401  0.866026
2  0.183609  0.316389  0.213718  0.707552  0.033736
```

#### Accessing the index

You can access the index directly, which in this case is a `pd.RangeIndex`:

```
print(df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

print(df.index.values)
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

#### Explicit test

You can check explicitly whether your column labels align with your data:

```
def check_csv(file_in):
    col_count = pd.read_csv(x, nrows=0, header=None).shape[1]                 # 5
    data_count = pd.read_csv(x, skiprows=[0], nrows=0, header=None).shape[1]  # 6
    return col_count == data_count

assert check_csv('file.csv'), 'Dataframe is malformed, check column labels versus data!'
```

The [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) statement will raise `AssertionError` when your CSV file is malformed.

Comment: Ah. But it is wreaking havoc! There are other malformed csvs for which error is raised but this is escaping attention!

Comment: @AnoopSaxena, Sure, I've updated with a check you can perform to discover when this happens.